# MS Visual Studio 2013 freezing interface and doesn't load

Tags: interface, visual-studio-2013, freeze

[image: Freezing interface]

My interface in Visual Studio 2013 is bugged i don't know why.. and how solve it.

On the picture interface is already "loaded". I can't even change project type..

It's not a first time. Any idea why my interface is freezing?

Regards,

Tagon.

**@EDIT:**

It is happens again.. None extension installed. I reinstalled even system, but it is same reaction.. After install VS2013 it works perfectly.. and after month I lunched VS and interface is again freezed.. One way to repait this problem for now is re-install whole VS.

Any ideas to avoid reinstall ?

Comment: What extensions are you using?

Comment: Now I have not any ext.. even reinstalled doesnt helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late but I just had this issue. I upgrade and it fixed it once, then happened next time I openend it. I was able to fix this by disabling hardware acceleration in VS Options.

Go to `Tools > Options > General >` Unchecking `Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance` & also unchecking `Use hardware graphics acceleration if available`